# Answering a closed question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

A recent question on stack overflow has been closed for posting a large (actually not that large really) block of code rather than using jsFiddle or similar. However I am pretty sure I have the answer and don't have enough reputation to vote for it being re-opened. What should I do? The comments suggest the op (a new user) has understood his/her mistake and it seems pretty unfriendly to refuse to help them out due to their unfamiliarity with the conventions of the site.

(apologies for no link to the question but I closed the tab and as the question has been closed am not sure how to find it again)

Comment: A closed question indicates that there are serious problems which make it unsuitable for answering. If you want to help, comment on the post and tell the OP to fix the problems so that it can be reopened.

Comment: Closed questions are not deleted; you can find the question using regular search.

Comment: Jsfiddle is discouraged if it's te only way you post the code. We want the smallest amount of code that reproduces the problem. JSFiddle links die.

Answer (score 3):

As also mentioned in the [FAQ for closed questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#close):

> Questions that [are not a good fit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) for this site may be voted closed by
>   experienced community members. Closed questions cannot be answered,
>   but are eligible for improvement (and eventual re-opening) through
>   editing, voting, and commenting.

Now, as you say that you might have a solution to the question, try answering it first in comments(if possible). However, if you still think that the question will help someone in future or in other words, it is not too localized and should be reopened; you can flag the post and explain your reasoning with a link to this thread on meta so that moderators will take appropriate actions and might also reply here.

Although, you could have provided the link to referenced question in this thread too.

Answer (score 1):

One approach, if you know the answer, is to try and edit the question to narrow down the problem. It sounds like the asker may not have done a good job of this, which is sort of a requirement for ensuring that the question and answer would be useful to future visitors. It's important that content here scales beyond just the original asker. While we do enjoy helping the asker, we also want to indirectly help the hundreds of future visitors who may very well be searching for solutions to the same or similar problem.

This is where you come in:  As someone who sees the problem and the solution, you're perhaps best suited to make the necessary improvements to turn the question into something the community would be happy to reopen.

If there's a large block of code in the question, a jsFiddle isn't necessarily the answer to improving the post since it would still lack the necessary focus to help others locate the problem they're facing. Instead, focus edits on conciseness and brevity.

If you locate the question, please drop a link to it in your meta question. Members of the community are happy to help improve the post if you can get the ball rolling. Hope this helps!